# L and R function in the vicinity of a SMPS output

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inductor

What is the Inductor L and Resistor R function in a SMPS output vicinity below after transormer T output?

What are the two values supposed to be calculated with respect to each other and to the two capacitors i.e. C1 and C2||C3?

[image]

Please help elaborate the real mechanism crystal clearly!

Comment: *What are the two values supposed to be* <--the two values are "unknown" as shown on the schematic. How could anyone reading the question be expected to say anything else without guessing? Maybe if you provided full details of the complete circuit and a better description of the product?

Answer (score 1):

R is just a bleeder resistor. If it was not present and there was no load the output volts could go too high or unstable . The bleeder does waste power so newer more efficient designs take other approaches to save power. L provides more filtering on the output. It is chosen to have low DCR to not affect the DC output but  significant impedance at the switching frequency and its harmonics.